# How to multicast large files in jgroups

Tags: java, multicast, jgroups

Let's say I have a relatively big file (about 100MB) that I want to multicast to all members of a cluster. How can I send the file in chunks using jgroups(with preferably a code demonstration)? The file should be read in chunks at the receivers side. Also how can I ensure the sequence order of the chunks is  maintained at the receivers side.

**EDIT 1**
Here is what I have tried so far. I just send the file as a whole and write its contents at the receivers' side to temporary file

```
    public class SimpleFileTransfer extends ReceiverAdapter {

    JChannel channel;

    private void start() throws Exception{
        channel = new JChannel();
        channel.setReceiver(this);
        channel.connect("FileCluster");
//        channel.getState(null, 10000);
        File file = new File("/res/test.txt"); //the file to be sent
        eventLoop(file);
        channel.close();
    }

    private void eventLoop(File file) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        try {
            Message msg = new Message(null, null, in);
            channel.send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void receive(Message msg)
    {
        try {
            File temp = new File("/res/temp.txt");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(temp);
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.getBuffer());
            int next = in.read();
            while (next != -1){
                writer.write(next);
                next = in.read();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ie)
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: This is not a site where people write code for you. Show what have you already tried, then people will help you out. Downvoting.

Comment: @We are Borg, Fair enough. I have updated  the question with what I tried so far.

Comment: @WeareBorg I think you made your point , you didnt have to downvote a rather very good question.

Comment: Downvote removed as the OP posted what was tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below's the better version, which chunks up large files into chunks of 8K.
A file X is written to /tmp/X. Note that the /home/bela/fast.xml config has to be changed, of course:

```
public class SimpleFileTransfer extends ReceiverAdapter {
protected String   filename;
protected JChannel channel;
protected Map<String,OutputStream> files=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
protected static final short ID=3500;

private void start(String name, String filename) throws Exception {
    ClassConfigurator.add((short)3500, FileHeader.class);
    this.filename=filename;
    channel=new JChannel("/home/bela/fast.xml").name(name);
    channel.setReceiver(this);
    channel.connect("FileCluster");
    eventLoop();
}

private void eventLoop() throws Exception {
    while(true) {
        Util.keyPress(String.format("<enter to send %s>\n", filename));
        sendFile();
    }
}

protected void sendFile() throws Exception {
    FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(filename);
    try {
        for(;;) {
            byte[] buf=new byte[8096];
            int bytes=in.read(buf);
            if(bytes == -1)
                break;
            sendMessage(buf, 0, bytes, false);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        sendMessage(null, 0, 0, true);
    }
}


public void receive(Message msg) {
    byte[] buf=msg.getRawBuffer();
    FileHeader hdr=(FileHeader)msg.getHeader(ID);
    if(hdr == null)
        return;
    OutputStream out=files.get(hdr.filename);
    try {
        if(out == null) {
            File tmp=new File(hdr.filename);
            String fname=tmp.getName();
            fname="/tmp/" + fname;
            out=new FileOutputStream(fname);
            files.put(hdr.filename, out);
        }
        if(hdr.eof) {
            Util.close(files.remove(hdr.filename));
        }
        else {
            out.write(msg.getRawBuffer(), msg.getOffset(), msg.getLength());
        }
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        System.err.println(t);
    }
}


protected void sendMessage(byte[] buf, int offset, int length, boolean eof) throws Exception {
    Message msg=new Message(null, buf, offset, length).putHeader(ID, new FileHeader(filename, eof));
    // set this if the sender doesn't want to receive the file
    // msg.setTransientFlag(Message.TransientFlag.DONT_LOOPBACK);
    channel.send(msg);
}

protected static class FileHeader extends Header {
    protected String  filename;
    protected boolean eof;

    public FileHeader() {} // for de-serialization

    public FileHeader(String filename, boolean eof) {
        this.filename=filename;
        this.eof=eof;
    }

    public int size() {
        return Util.size(filename) + Global.BYTE_SIZE;
    }

    public void writeTo(DataOutput out) throws Exception {
        Util.writeObject(filename, out);
        out.writeBoolean(eof);
    }

    public void readFrom(DataInput in) throws Exception {
        filename=(String)Util.readObject(in);
        eof=in.readBoolean();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if(args.length != 2) {
        System.out.printf("%s <name> <filename>\n", SimpleFileTransfer.class.getSimpleName());
        return;
    }
    new SimpleFileTransfer().start(args[0], args[1]); // name and file
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Below's the bad solution. To run it, the config needs to have bundler_type="sender-sends" (in UDP) and the app needs enough memory.
This solution is bad because it reads the entire file into a buffer, which is copied once of twice in JGroups as well.
The next solution I'll post is better because it chunks that large file up into multiple smaller chunks. Note that sending the large file, JGroups does internal chunking (fragmentation) too, but you still have to create that large byte[] buffer on the application level, which is bad.

```
public class SimpleFileTransfer extends ReceiverAdapter {
protected String   filename;
protected JChannel channel;

private void start(String name, String filename) throws Exception {
    this.filename=filename;
    channel=new JChannel("/home/bela/fast.xml").name(name);
    channel.setReceiver(this);
    channel.connect("FileCluster");
    eventLoop();
    channel.close();
}

private void eventLoop() throws Exception {
    while(true) {
        Util.keyPress(String.format("<enter to send %s>\n", filename));
        sendFile();
    }
}

protected void sendFile() throws Exception {
    Buffer buffer=readFile(filename);
    try {
        Message msg=new Message(null, buffer);
        channel.send(msg);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void receive(Message msg) {
    System.out.printf("received %s from %s\n", Util.printBytes(msg.getLength()), msg.src());
    try {
        File temp=new File("/tmp/temp.txt");
        FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(temp);
        InputStream in=new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.getBuffer());
        int next=in.read();
        while(next != -1) {
            writer.write(next);
            next=in.read();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}


protected static Buffer readFile(String filename) throws Exception {
    File file=new File(filename);
    int size=(int)file.length();
    FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(file);
    ByteArrayDataOutputStream out=new ByteArrayDataOutputStream(size);
    byte[] read_buf=new byte[1024];
    int bytes;
    while((bytes=input.read(read_buf)) != -1)
        out.write(read_buf, 0, bytes);
    return out.getBuffer();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if(args.length != 2) {
        System.out.printf("%s <name> <filename>\n", SimpleFileTransfer.class.getSimpleName());
        return;
    }
    new SimpleFileTransfer().start(args[0], args[1]); // name and file
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No one is going to write the code for you, but:

1. Turn file into Byte Array
2. Break array into chunks
3. Wrap each chunk in an envelope that says which piece it is
4. Send the chunks
5. Read the envelope Put them back together again

None of these things individually are very hard.

Comment: Your update makes no difference to the advice I gave